# Is there a way to add a .log file to an existing workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to add the content of a log file to a workbook witch have a certaine format to it.

By doing : `Set sourcebook = Workbooks.Open("the log file")`

it open the log file in a new workbook sheet. is there a way to add it to an existing workbook with the format of an existing sheet?

Comment: If a text file, just [import it](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba).

Comment: well it's a log file

Comment: What's the extension? Either way you need to import it instead of opening it.

Comment: @BigBen it's a `.log`type of file. but by importing it as a `.txt`file i was able to change the extension to `all` and it worked! thanks for the help

Comment: .... and I just realized you had `.log` in the title... shoulda read more carefully, my bad :-)

Comment: A .log file is typically just a plain text file, either comma- or tab-delimited